# What is the song at the end of episode 6 of "Kenichi: The Mightiest Disciple"?

Tags: music, historys-strongest-disciple-kenichi

Which song plays in episode 6 of *Kenichi: The Mightiest Disciple* at around the 21:40 mark? It's before the actual ending credits. It sounded a bit like the opening but changed up. But I don't think that's it.

Comment: I've rephrased the question a bit for you to better fit in with the quality we like to achieve. I'd suggest you take the [tour](https://anime.stackexchange.com/tour), it tells you how to phrase questions for the future and such. Beyond that, welcome to A&M ^^

Answer (score 0):

I think that they used the instrumental song : **Koike Joanna - Catch your dreams (Karaoke Version)**

And they added the lyrics on a little part of that Karaoke Version, that they repeated.

You can find it here : http://www.ost-center.com/ost/anime/shijou-saikyou-no-deshi-kenichi-ed2-single-catch-your-dream-ost-7262.html